# How to find quartile value for every column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Find the Quartiles values for each and every column in my dataset in just one go with my dataset names as df4. How do I do that?

I tried using For loop but didnt really got the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide an example of your dataset and the current code that you're using? It would be more helpful to do this from now for your future questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the np.percentile function with the required quartile/percentile values you need for each of the column and finally extract the values in the form of dictionary. You can refer to the code snippet

```
import numpy as np

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2': [4,5,6,7,8,9]})
perc_df = {}

for c in df4.columns:
    q_list = []
    for i in [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]: #add the quartile list 
        p = np.percentile(np.array(df4[c]), i)
        q_list.append(p)
    perc_df[c] = q_list #add the quartile values for the column
    
pd.DataFrame(perc_df)
```